# How to use rxjs pipes directly on ngxs selectors

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I can not seem to find an elegant way to directly interact with the data from the selector, in the view. Something like sorting by an id or another dynamic value.

I know that i can use dynamic/lazy selectors, but sometimes i dont want to add properties to my state just to accomplish a simple UI task.

For instance, if i want to take the first value from currentJobsStories$ and set it as the 'active' Story on init i have no simple way to do so.

```
@Select(StoryState.currentJobsStories) currentJobsStories$: Observable<Story[]>;


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentJobsStories$.pipe(
      map(story => {
        this.filteredStories = [...story];
        return story;
      }),
    );
  }
```

The code inside of the pipe is never executed, even though i am subscribing with the async pipe in the html.

Is there a way to simply pipe into the data from a select?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to transform the result of a `Selector` for the purposes of this component only then you need to define a new `Observable` for use in your template (which you've *almost* done here, just missing the assignment).

```
@Select(StoryState.currentJobsStories) currentJobsStories$: Observable<Story[]>;

myCurrentJobsStories$: Observable<Story[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {

 this.myCurrentJobsStories$ = this.currentJobsStories$.pipe(
      map(story => {
        this.filteredStories = [...story];
        return story;
      }),
    );
}
```

Then in your component template you need to subscribe to new `Observable` via `myCurrentJobsStories$ | async`